# div is not moving with the mouse pointer when the pointer is over the div itself

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I want to move a div with the mouse pointer but the div is not moving smoothly. When the pointer comes over the div it will not move until the pointer is out of the div and when it comes out of the div the div is suddenly moving for those much pixels
This is what I've tried

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/94FbY/)

.css

```
#a
{
   width:400px;
   height:300px;
   background:yellow;
}
#b
{
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   background:red;
}
```

html

```
<div id="a">
   <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$(function(){
   $('#a').mousemove(function (e) {
      var offset = $(this).offset()
      var x = (e.pageX - offset.left);
      var y = (e.pageY - offset.top);
      $('#b').css({ left: x, top: y });
   }); 
});
```

Comment: The fiddle you shared is not moving at all...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nz8Jr/

working fine here in chrome. what browser?

Comment: why my fiddle is not working. I think your is similar to mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `position: absolute;` like so:

```
#b
{
   position: absolute;
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   background:red;
}
```